# Why would a NOTAM outage cause a nationwide ground stop?

Tags: faa, notam

From [the FAA this morning](https://twitter.com/FAANews/status/1613135903010033665)

> The FAA is working to restore its Notice to Air Missions System. We are performing final validation checks and reloading the system now.
>
> Operations across the National Airspace System are affected.

This apparently caused a complete ground stop for the whole US. Why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NOTAMS contain information about potential hazards and other mission-critical information that is short-lived (so not worth printing on charts) or otherwise breaking news kind of stuff.

Without that information, pilots will be unaware of dangers that may be involved in their flight.

VFR traffic was exempt from the stop, presumably because VFR flying relies far more on pilots' own ability/requirement to detect obstacles/trouble, and GA (which operate under looser regulations and may choose to accept more risk than airlines are allowed to accept on behalf of their passengers) were among the first to be additionally exempted prior to the ground stop itself being lifted.

But airlines are heavily regulated and aren't allowed to depart without reviewing the NOTAMS relevant to their flight path and if the NOTAM system is offline they're unable to meet that regulatory requirement.

Comment: I don't know what this particular NOTAM ground stop stated regarding the type of operations that were affected, but even General Aviation VFR traffic are subject to information published in NOTAMs. Your answer gives the impression that General Aviation (VFR) operations need not care (ever) about NOTAMs, which is incorrect.

Comment: @757toga I'll edit. I was listening to KBOS_GND/DEL when it dropped which is how I know VFR traffic was exempt from the ground stop.

Comment: This answer is largely correct with the exception of the presumption about VFR.  Whatever the reason for the VFR exemption, it wouldn't be for the reason stated.  NOTAMs often contain information vital to the safe conduct of VFR flights, cf https://www.notaminfo.com/latest?country=UK+Channel%20Isles

Comment: @Dave Grimlin That's true. Ask any VFR pilot that accidentally flew into a Presidential TFR.

Comment: I think VFR traffic was allowed due to the need for life-safety flights, e.g. medevac, SAR, firefighting, to continue.

Comment: @user71659 ISTR they also explicitly exempted Medivac flights and the like separately, but it's now been 12 hours or so since I heard it so I may be mistaken on that.

Comment: @user71659: it was originally a complete 100% everybody GS, then they exempted medevac and military, then they exempted VFR, then they exempted IFR general aviation, then they exempted flights to ATL and EWR, then they also exempted flights to IAD, then they lifted the stop entirely.

Comment: I think a better question is:  Why, if this system is so critical, does it not have some sort of redundant backup that would immediately kick in to avoid a complete shutdown like this?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman AIUI, they did have a backup system... but that backup system had the same corrupted file so it also failed.